# Insertar en Laravel utlizando un modelo

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo este metodo que crea un Usuario

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'surname' => 'required|max:255',
            'infrastructure_id' => 'required|numeric',
            'in_code' => 'required',
            'address' => 'required|max:255',
            'issue' => 'required',
            'phone'=> 'required|numeric',
            'lat' => 'required|numeric',
            'long' => 'required|numeric',
            'IP' => 'required|numeric'
        ]);
        $ip = \Request::ip()
        return Pqr::create($validatedData);
     }
```

Como puedo para hacer para al campo IP almacenar por defecto el valor de la IP del cliente que se obtiene con el metodo `\Request::ip()` si tengo el modelo PQR ?

El campo IP no estaria en el formulario sino que el obtenga el IP a traves del metodo y este se almacene automaticamente sin que escriba.

Comment: ¿cómo está definido el campo ip en la migración?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de guardar tu objeto solo instancialo a una variable:

```
$pqr=new Pqr($request->all());
```

Luego le asignas la ip:

```
$pqr->ip=\Request::ip();
```

Para posteriormente guardarlo:

```
$pqr->save();
```

Y listo eso deberia de funcionar.

**Codigo Completo:**

```
$pqr=new Pqr($request->all());
$pqr->ip=\Request::ip();
$pqr->save();
return $pqr;
```